# Awesomium javascript-related crash/freeze

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, awesomium

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered problems with Awesomium relating to a WebView that goes unresponsive with a light blue screen if there is a problem with JS in the loaded script.

I'm developing in C# and with Awesomium 1.7 RC3. If the underlying javascript can't be executed due to a syntax error for example, the entire page will render blank. Outside of awesomium, it renders the HTML and displays the page. I'm handling the Crashed event, it's not being called. The app, nor the WebView is actually crashing. I've tried using both a windowed WebView instance and a WebControl instance, but the issue remains.

I've searched thoroughly for someone experiencing a similar problem, but seems I'm the only one. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me !!
I don't understand

EDIT : 
It seems that the LoadHTML function is limited in size, so the page breaks !

I load the minimum on loadhtml and then execute more script in the documntready event, with the executejavascript function.

It seems to work for me even with larger data.

Ex :

```
Helper.ProjectTimeLine.webControl.DocumentReady += (object s, UrlEventArgs ee) =>
{
    Helper.ProjectTimeLine.webControl.ExecuteJavascript("window.source = " + DynamicJson.Serialize(source));
    Helper.ProjectTimeLine.webControl.ExecuteJavascript("start();");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this, and it performed a blue screen:

```
string result = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("Game.server_time");
```

I solved the problem simply by adding a null character at the end:

```
string result = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("Game.server_time+''");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but you sholud write your answers in english.